# i want to parse data from multiple json+id tags using python from website

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

i am looking for someone whos can help me. i want to parse data from JSON+ID tags. in this website, there are 3 different JSON+ID tags i want data from 1st one tag. but it automatically parses data from 2nd tag which i don't need. there is an link https://www.wayfair.com/home-improvement/pdp/orren-ellis-lina-36-single-bathroom-vanity-set-oris2048.html

here is my code

```
import requests as re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import json
import csv


source=re.get("https://www.wayfair.com/home-improvement/pdp/orren-ellis-lina-36-single-bathroom-vanity-set-oris2048.html")
parse=bs(source.text,'html.parser')
js = json.loads(parse.find("script",type="application/ld+json").text)
print(js)
```

its only give me this output

```
<script type="application/ld+json">{"@context":"http://schema.org","@type":"WebSite","name":"Wayfair","url":"https://www.wayfair.com"}</script>
```

but i want this tag json+id tag data not other one

```
<script type="application/ld+json">{"@context":"http://schema.org","@type":"Product","name":"Lina 36\" Single Bathroom Vanity Set","brand":"Orren Ellis","sku":"ORIS2048","url":"https://www.wayfair.com/home-improvement/pdp/orren-ellis-lina-36-single-bathroom-vanity-set-oris2048.html","image":"https://secure.img1-fg.wfcdn.com/im/68800231/compr-r85/3930/39308112/lina-36-single-bathroom-vanity-set.jpg","aggregateRating":{"@type":"AggregateRating","reviewCount":67,"ratingValue":4.5},"offers":{"@type":"Offer","availability":"http://schema.org/InStock","priceCurrency":"USD","price":476.99},"review":[{"@type":"Review","author":"Christine","datePublished":"2018-12-02","description":"Love this decision. Delivery was a breeze and it looks very expensive compared to the price. Quality is great. My contractor added the marble backsplash to protect the walls. I wish the drawers were feels lighter for my hair products to stand up, but that would have compromised the look. Really happy with the deidsion.","reviewRating":{"@type":"Rating","bestRating":5,"ratingValue":5,"worstRating":1}},{"@type":"Review","author":"Darryle","datePublished":"2019-04-22","description":"Very happy with this vanity, exactly what we wanted and were looking for. Have to do some more work on the bathroom, including the wall (so don't mind the mess)--so it can hang evenly, and then we'll fully attach the sink, that's why there looks like there is a gap between the cabinets and sink top, in case you notice. Wanted to include pictures because I appreciate them when I'm shopping. Would definitely recommend!","reviewRating":{"@type":"Rating","bestRating":5,"ratingValue":5,"worstRating":1}},{"@type":"Review","author":"Lisa","datePublished":"2019-07-12","description":"I love the wide vanity top when doing my makeup and hair.  The drawers are deep and can hold plenty of toiletries and towels.","reviewRating":{"@type":"Rating","bestRating":5,"ratingValue":5,"worstRating":1}},{"@type":"Review","author":"Angela","datePublished":"2019-08-11","description":"Perfect for a small bathroom. However,,the color rosewood I ordered is a walnut color.","reviewRating":{"@type":"Rating","bestRating":5,"ratingValue":5,"worstRating":1}},{"@type":"Review","author":"Marianela","datePublished":"2019-05-04","description":"Oh so so beautiful and well made.","reviewRating":{"@type":"Rating","bestRating":5,"ratingValue":5,"worstRating":1}},{"@type":"Review","author":"Howard","datePublished":"2019-04-16","description":"Great vanity.  The finish is fantastic.   We are very pleased with our choice.","reviewRating":{"@type":"Rating","bestRating":5,"ratingValue":5,"worstRating":1}},{"@type":"Review","author":"Corinne","datePublished":"2018-10-17","description":"Great looking vanity! Sink has straight modern lines.","reviewRating":{"@type":"Rating","bestRating":5,"ratingValue":5,"worstRating":1}},{"@type":"Review","author":"Mara I.","datePublished":"2018-11-20","description":"Beautifull","reviewRating":{"@type":"Rating","bestRating":5,"ratingValue":5,"worstRating":1}},{"@type":"Review","author":"Argentina","datePublished":"2019-08-25","description":"It\u2019s perfect... i love it","reviewRating":{"@type":"Rating","bestRating":5,"ratingValue":5,"worstRating":1}},{"@type":"Review","author":"Benjamin","datePublished":"2019-08-24","description":"Clean, modern style.  Easy install","reviewRating":{"@type":"Rating","bestRating":5,"ratingValue":5,"worstRating":1}}]}</script>
```

Comment: I don't understand, it seems to be working fine?

Comment: thanks for the comment. sir did you check image

Comment: it's working but i need first_one tag data. but when i compile code it's give me 2nd tag data

Comment: Please share **all** relevant code and data, and as text, not images. See, amongst others: [mcve], [ask].

Comment: sir, i have mentioned my complete code please lookup

Comment: @usamariaz Did you check that the element is indeed present in the source? What have you done to try to debug this, how do you usually write web scraping programs?

Answer (score 0):

The data you want can only be retrieved by adding a cookie to the request. Try the following methods

```
from simplified_scrapy.simplified_doc import SimplifiedDoc 
from simplified_scrapy.request import req
# first request, get cookies
html = req.get('https://www.wayfair.com/home-improvement/pdp/orren-ellis-lina-36-single-bathroom-vanity-set-oris2048.html')
# second request, get the aim content
html = req.get('https://www.wayfair.com/home-improvement/pdp/orren-ellis-lina-36-single-bathroom-vanity-set-oris2048.html')
doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
item1 = doc.getElement('script',attr='type',value='application/ld+json') 
print(item1.html)
```